# Where should I store files for my web-app?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I'm developing a web-app to deploying to Heroku. However, even if I start the application by Tomcat, my BufferedReader can't find it, because the current directory is `/home/vladyour/Programs/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M19/bin`.

Where should I store files for my web-app? And how to address to them?

Thank you!

Comment: What are those files? Where do they come from? What do you do with them? How are you reading them?

Comment: Are they static files? If so, store it in the classpath and load them with ClassLoader.getResource()

Comment: @JBNizet those are .csv files. They don't come from anywhere. They should be stored in some folder (that I don't know). I'm reading it by BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))

Comment: If it is a static file, then you should create a resources folder in your project, and put your file here. Then get your file via ClassLoader.getResources()

Comment: @MinhKieu Yes, they are static. But, as I got it, ClassLoader.getResources will return "/home/vladyour/Programs/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M19/bin". It would by wrong to store my files there.

Comment: @VladYurevich - ClassLoader.getResource() can only read files packaged within your .jar or .war or app classpath. If you starts up Tomcat inside bin directory then that would be your home folder. As Tuyen Nguyen said, if you build your project using Maven, putting the files inside resources folder, Maven will include them in your application classpath, inside the .war or .jar

Answer (score 0):

you can add your **war file** or **upacked files** under
 /home/vladyour/Programs/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M19/webapps

and you can address them by
"address-ip":"tomcat-port"/'name-of your-app-at-webapps-dir"